# memoir headers with starred chapter

Tags: header-footer, memoir, chapters

I need help with page layout in `memoir`.
I want to have an unnumbered chapter0 (i.e. introduction) but when using the `\chapter` starred version the chapter headers is wrong.
This is my example source:

```
\documentclass[14pt,extrafontsizes,a4paper,twoside,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\raggedbottomsection

\begin{document}
%
\OnehalfSpacing
%
\frontmatter
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{DoubleSpace}
\tableofcontents*
\end{DoubleSpace}
\clearforchapter

\mainmatter

\pagestyle{ruled}
\chapter*{chapter0}
\label{chap:chapter0}

\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

\chapter{chapter1}
\label{chap:chapter1}

\section{ch1-s1}
\lipsum
\section{ch1-s2}
\lipsum
\section{ch1-s3}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\chapter*{last}
\label{chap:last}

\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

And the problem is in chapter0 and in "last".
Can you help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the optional argument provided for `\chapter` (works for `\chapter*` as well):

```
\chapter*[chapter0]{chapter0}
```

This will set the `\chaptermark` accordingly, and correct the headers. Why is this the case? Let's look at `\@m@mschapter` from [`memoir.cls`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir):

```
\newcommand{\@m@mschapter}[2][\@empty]{%
  \@schapter{#2}%
  \ifx \@empty#1
    \def\f@rhdr{#2}%
  \else%                    opt arg
    \def\f@rhdr{#1}%
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-10}%
    \chaptermark{#1}%
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{\value{maxsecnumdepth}}%
  \fi
  \ifanappendix
    \memappchapstarinfo{\f@rhdr}{#2}%
  \else
    \memchapstarinfo{\f@rhdr}{#2}%
  \fi
  \ifheadnameref\M@gettitle{\f@rhdr}\else\M@gettitle{#2}\fi}
```

The optional argument is set to `\@empty` if not specified manually. Subsequently, the macro conditions on whether `#1` (the optional argument) is `\@empty` or not, and specifying `\chaptermark` accordingly.

Note that using `\label` in an un-numbered sectional unit doesn't help.