# Retaining chapter page headers with chapter*{}

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

My question is essentially a duplicate of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74764/81618) but for the `book` class (for which the solution does not work), namely:

- If I have an un-numbered front-matter chapter (i.e. `\chapter*{A chapter}`), how can I set the correct chaptermark as if it were a numbered chapter?

Here's a MWE where chapter 2 still has chapter 1's chaptermark:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{arsclassica} % optional
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chap1}
\lipsum

\chapter*{Chap2}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

I think possibly the answer is contained in the [comment thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4002358/1274516) under an SO answer, but it's a bit cryptic, suggesting "Try adding \chaptermark{#1} resp. \leftmark / \rightmark.".

(Aside: I'm using the `arsclassica` package so ideally don't want to overwrite the current `chaptermark` style.)

Comment: you can insert `\markboth{Chap2}` after the `\chapter*` line.

Comment: `\markboth{Chap2}{Chap2}` fixed the chaptermark text but also changes the style

Comment: `arsclassica` is based on `scrreport`, part of the `koma` collection, so i have added that identifier to the tags.  it's my opinion that the failure to handle running heads properly for starred chapters is a design flaw; as such, it might profitably be brought to the attention of the `arsclassica` developer, whose address is included in the (very nice) documentation.

Comment: What's the problem in having the chapter after `\frontmatter` and before `\mainmatter`? Anyway, I'm not sure that `arsclassica` should be used with `book`, but rather with `scrbook`. It's different with `classicthesis` that purports to support both classes.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91468/510

Comment: I didn't realise being in frontmatter removed the need for the starred function, that fixes my issue so happy to accept that as an answer if you want to move this out of unanswered. (Also `book` -> `scrbook` makes some subtle + interesting changes, thanks for that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As egreg pointed out, the solution was to just use `\chapter` throughout `\frontmatter`.

Where `arsclassica` was failing to give the correctedly-formatted chapter marks for (e.g.) `\listoftables`, `\tableofcontents` etc., I instead used:

```
\chapter{Contents}

\makeatletter
\@starttoc{toc} % or lof, lot etc.
\makeatother
```