# Bibliography header inconsistency with my page style using a memoir class

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, header-footer, memoir, pagestyle

I want to have `Bibliography` as a header title in my bibliography (starting obviously from the second page). But, the title of the previous chapters appears instead!

I am using `Memoir` class with `biblatex`. with my pagestyle named as: `MyPageStyle`

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makepagestyle{MyPageStyle}
\copypagestyle{MyPageStyle}{ruled}
\makeoddhead{MyPageStyle}{\textsl\leftmark}{}{}

\pagestyle{MyPageStyle}

\usepackage[natbib=true, backend=biber, url=false, isbn=false, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}


\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext


\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

here is a snapshot of my problem

[image]

Any idea on how to solve that?

There is [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74765/165284) but I don't know how to make it work with my specific problem!

### Edit 1:

I have tried to change `\leftmark` with `\rightmark` as suggested by `@daleif`. It solved the Bibliography headers, but the other chapters (numbered, unnumbered, appendix) remain un-headed! (see my updated MWE below).

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{memoir}


\usepackage{blindtext}


\makepagestyle{MyPageStyle}
\copypagestyle{MyPageStyle}{ruled}
\makeoddhead{MyPageStyle}{\textsl\rightmark}{}{}

\pagestyle{MyPageStyle}


\usepackage[natbib=true, backend=biber, url=false, isbn=false, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}


\mainmatter

\chapter[Ch. w/ N.]{Numbered Chapter}
\Blindtext

\chapter*[Ch. w/o  N.]{Unnumbered Chapter}
\Blindtext

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\appendix

\chapter[Specs.]{Specification}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

How to solve these inconsistencies?

Comment: Under `oneside` you should use `\rightmark` instead. For example the standard memoir `headings` style only writes to `\rightmark` under `oneside`. Looking at `biblatex.def` this is  exactly what biblatex does under `oneside`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `oneside` you should use `\rightmark` as this is what most header data providers only write to under `oneside`.

For the added question:

Not many of the page styles have a `oneside` and a `twoside` variant. The default `headings` does. The style `ruled` does not. Meaning that `\chapter` will only write to `\leftmark`. IMO the default for `\chapter` should be to write to both (which I normally do in all of my own documents). It is too late to change this now.

Here is how to add `bothness`:

```
\addtopsmarks{MyPageStyle}{}{
  \createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{}{. \space}
}
```

add it somewhere after `\copypagestyle{MyPageStyle}{ruled}` and before `\pagestyle{MyPageStyle}`

The psmarks control what and to where macros like `\chapter`, TOC etc write their stuff

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Could you see my updated question? Your answer of replacing `leftmark` by `rightmark` works, but just for the bibliography. The other chapters become unheaded

Comment: @Talha see the update. Note that technically you probably ought to have made a separate question about this.

Comment: Yeah. Propbaly. Thank youso much. It worked.